# Making Excel report into SSRS with Pivot Tables

Tags: sql, reporting-services, pivot, reporting

I am trying to create a SSRS report from an ad hoc script I have. I can get results but the user of the report requests certain pivots that I can not seem to correctly display the information.

Below is an export of the report from sql with the pivots added. I want each row to be grouped by the GRADE first, OD second, and ID third. The pivot is adjusted for the STOCK NUMBERs. Each row with matching grade,OD, and ID will have numerous stock numbers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFKl1.png

This is the closest I have have came to displaying the information in SSRS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjlPF.png

Is there anyway I can have the Stock numbers run across a single row instead of a row for each stock number?

Comment: One way to do this is to modify the script to use the PIVOT operator to flatten out those columns. How best to do that depends on the max number of stock numbers.

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this. Do you have anymore information you can provide on the Pivot operator. the max stock numbers I will have will probably be less than 10, Around 6 probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little more tricky than I thought. Since I did not want the Stock Number to actually be a column header but to just list on each column corresponding to my group it was not an actual pivot and was why it was not working properly.

Basically to get it to work I had to use the LookUpSet+Join function in SSRS to list the stock numbers out. I was not required to list them out on different columns. Thank-you for your replies.

Here is the code I used in the column

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!grade.Value & Fields!od.Value & Fields!wall.Value & Fields!id.Value, Fields!grade.Value & Fields!od.Value & Fields!wall.Value & Fields!id.Value, RTrim(Fields!stock_number.Value), "FOC"), ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Column Group based on Stock number.  That will generate a column for each Stock number.